# SelectedValue is invalid...I know why but I dont know how to handle it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I've got a gridview / datagrid in asp.net that has template columns (I don't use databound columns).
Inside of one of these columns is a dropdownlist.  Basically this drop down list's datasource is a query that stores our active users...we don't want to show all inactive and active users because of the size of the dataset so we limit to active.

Basically the sql is something to this effect:

`SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employee WHERE Inactive=0`

This works fine, but I have a record that actually references an inactive employee, this rarely happens but there are cases when this could happen.  Outside of a gridview using a dropdownlist just on the page I can easily handle this by try / catching the exception and reloading the dropdown so that it can also contain the inactive employee.

But inside of a gridview I don't know how to "Catch" this exception as the column simply has a:

`SelectedValue ='<%# Eval("EmployeeName") %>'`

So because the page is referencing an inactive employee I get the error:

> ddlEmployees' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ddlEmployees'
>   has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the
>   list of items. Parameter name: value

So I know why this is happening, and I could actually fix this if this were a dropdownlist outside of the gridview, but because it is in the gridview Im not sure how to handle this?

Do I need ot handle this in the RowDataBound event?  Or is there some asp.net markup that just says ignore if its a bad value?  Something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployees" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Employee") == null ? 0 : Eval("Employee") %>'
```

Could I even use the ternary operator?

Comment: can you update the question with the code how you bind DropDownList?

Answer (score 1):

Use this one for your Dropdownlist. I assume `EmployeeName` is a Column here and lets suppose this can have null values possible. [ Supply a correct Column name of yours ]

```
SelectedValue='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Bind("EmployeeName")))
                                                 ? "0" : Bind("EmployeeName") %>'
```

Also, you can do this in your Sql statement itself:

```
SELECT IsNull(EmployeeName,0) AS EmployeeName FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove selected value from dropdown in the aspx.Define datasource and datamember like the below code.Hope it will help you..

```
 try
             {

                 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                 {
                     DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlSorting");
                     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID,EmployeeName FROM Employee WHERE Inactive=0", con);
                     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                     da.Fill(ds);
                     ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                     ddl.DataTextField = "EmployeeName";
                     ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
                     ddl.DataBind();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                             }
```